# Define a method for a List of customClass

Tags: java, list, methods

I'm writing a plugin, and have some custom classes already built.
The way I've written everything so far (around 1000 lines), using a list is the most convenient way to store the class instances, so I've got a few lines at the top of the main class like `public List<Job> Jobs;`.
In the Job class, for example's sake, I have a field called `name`.
I'm wondering if there's a way to define a method for `List<Job>` because I would like to have a simpler way to figure out if any of the `Job`s in the list have a `name` matching something and then what that job's index would be in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a class that encapsulates your `List<Job>` and provides a method that performs the search, or you could just write it as a local method. Either way, it will need to iterate through all the `Job` objects in the list looking for a match.

Alternatively, you could keep an additional `Map<String, Job>`, which would allow you to look up a specific `Job` using it's name.

Comment: I've not used Maps before, though they seem simple. Would keeping that Map store a second copy of the Job's instance, or just a reference?

Comment: Just a reference. Just remember that each time you add to your array, you also add to the map, and when deleting from your array, delete from the map.